# How to combine 3 tableGrob together without making a mess?

Tags: r, gridextra

I have a matrix with rowhead (sequence) and colhead (sequence) that must be displayed. Here  is the code for such matrix and the output :

### sim matrix

```
  m <- tableGrob(sim_df[1:10, 1:10], theme=ttheme_default(
                  core=list(fg_params=list(col=fg_cols), bg_params = list(fill=bg_cols, col="black")),
                  colhead=list(bg_params=list(fill="white", col="black")), 
                  rowhead=list(fg_params=list(fontface="bold"), bg_params=list(fill="white", 
col="black"))))
```

[sim matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VXkxN.png)

Now, I want to add extra labels (name, year) in the headers. Here are the outputs :

```
  # rows' labels
  m1 <- tableGrob(df_r[1:10, 1:2], theme=ttheme_default(
                  core=list(fg_params=list(col="black"), bg_params = list(fill="white", col="black")),
                  colhead=list(fg_params=list(col="white"), bg_params=list(fill="white", col="white"))),
                  rows=NULL)
```

[m1 - row labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f9s0W.png)

```
   # columns' labels
  m2 <- tableGrob(df_c[1:2, 1:10], theme=ttheme_default(
                  core=list(fg_params=list(col="black"), bg_params = list(fill="white", col="black")),
                  rowhead=list(fg_params=list(col="white"), bg_params=list(fill="white", col="white"))),
                  cols=NULL)
```

[m2 - column labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLp0z.png)

I have managed to combine the tableGrobs m1 + m and m2 + m. Here are the two outputs :

```
r_align <- gtable_combine(m1, m, along=1)
```

[r_align - extra labels for rownames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mz7GZ.png)

```
c_align <- gtable_combine(m2, m, along=2)
```

[c_align - extra labels for colnames](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzBvH.png)

**That being said, once I want to combine the extra labels on the rownames and the colnames, it simply wont align and it removes two columns in the process.**

As mentionned earlier, by doing :

```
r_align <- gtable_combine(m1, m, along=1)
```

we get the matrix with extra labels for the rows. Once we try to combine this r_align with the m2 labels for the colnames extras :

```
final_align <- gtable_combine(m2, r_align, along=2)
```

[we get the following product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VtZSa.png)

The expected result is :
[expectations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ETkiR.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue by using cbind() instead of gtable_combine() for the rows label alignment to the similarity matrix.